# include en plantilla ejs

Tags: nodejs, ejs, express

Estoy haciendo un `render` recursivo y bastante simple de esta forma en `express`

```
// index.js
const VIEWS = __dirname + '/app/views/';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(VIEWS + 'includes/partials/body', {layout: VIEWS + 'dashboard/home'});
});
```

Ahora bien, mi archivo `app/views/includes/partials/body.ejs` es el siguiente

```
<!-- Start body and layout -->
<% include header %> <!-- Esto carga correctamente -->
<div class="container">
    <% include(layout) %>
    <!-- layout es una variable con valor app/views/dashboard/home -->
    <!-- como se puede ver arriba en mi res.render() -->
</div>
<% include footer %> <!-- Esto carga correctamente -->
<!-- End body and layout -->
```

Este es mi archivo `app/views/dashboard/home.ejs`

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

Por más que cambie el contenido de `app/views/dashboard/home` o le de otro valor a la variable `layout` por otra ruta con otro archivo y otro `html` diferente SIEMPRE me da como resultado esto:

```
<!-- Start header -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>yT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">yT</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul id="supertabs" class="nav navbar-nav" data-tabs="supertabs">
                        <li><a href="#y" data-toggle="tab">y</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#T" data-toggle="tab">T</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">c</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
<!-- End header -->
<!-- Start body and layout -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Aquí debería renderizarse un <h1>Home</h1> -->
    <!-- Pero nunca lo hace :C -->
</div>
<!-- End body and layout -->
<!-- Start footer -->
    <script src="./public/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./private/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- End footer -->
```

Es decir que `include(layout)` NUNCA me renderiza lo que hay dentro de dicho archivo en dicha ruta, ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: La verdad lo instalé con un simple npm i --save ejs ese es el que estoy usando, ahora estoy del móvil, mañana temprano reviso tus links

Comment: @Jorious, ya estoy de vuelta. Dime, ¿te aseguras que layout tenga un valor válido? Puede ser que por algún motivo no lo tenga. Otra cosa, ¿En la consola no ves ningún warning?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Si, estoy completamente seguro que layout tiene un valor válido y no, no aparece ningún error ni ningún warning

Comment: En lugar de cargar el layout, imprime en un `h1` el valor de `layout` para ver la ruta.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía La ruta es válida, el archivo .ejs de la ruta tiene contenido html, si remuevo el `include(layout)` y pongo un `<%= layout %>` me muestra correctamente el texto dentro de la variable

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Ya lo resolví

Comment: ¿Cuál era el problema?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Ya publiqué mi respuesta por si te es útil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví leyendo [aquí](https://github.com/mde/ejs) la documentación en [github](https://github.com/mde/ejs) en el apartado de **Tags**.

Agregando un guión ( **-** ) donde realizo el `include(layout)` se emite el valor de la variable layout sin escapar y así correctamente carga el archivo .ejs:

```
<!-- Start body and layout -->
<%- include('header') %> 
<!-- 
Esto lo cambie para un mejor uso del motor
y le agregué un guión ( - ) después de la <% para 
"emitir el valor sin escape en la plantilla"
-->
<div class="container">
    <%- include(layout) %> <!-- Al igual que aquí le agrego el guión ( - ) -->
</div>
<%- include('footer') %> <!-- Al igual que cambié esto para lo primeramente mencionado --> 
<!-- End body and layout -->
```